# Can't get wine to install Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, software-center, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dependency error while installing WINE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204840/dependency-error-while-installing-wine)

I have just successfully installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer and I got it to duel boot with windows 7.  My problem is that I want to use windows games (like halo combat involved) inside Ubuntu.  So I went to the Ubuntu software center and tried to install wine so I could do that.  But it doesn't install and gives me this message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.7ubuntu6 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu20 is to be installed
     Depends: wine1.4-amd64 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1) but 1.4.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: This is about non installable packages so system info is unneeded and answers with "go use windows" are already unacceptable on askubuntu. Please be brief and stay ontopic in a question ;)

Comment: And to make things worse. It has been asked before [Dependency error while installing WINE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204840/dependency-error-while-installing-wine) See the answer by dchampagne. The bug reports I saw about this state it is a problem with architecture (and that answer is about solving that).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the WineHQ Ubuntu Page: http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

You first have to install the PPA (Wine 1.4 is not supported in 12.10 as far as I know. It also gives me some errors. You need to use Wine 1.5). For best results use the PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa -y`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install wine1.5`

Then open `winecfg` to finish the install/configuration process.

Remember that with `winetricks` you can install any additional 3rd party programs that a game would need like Visual Basic Runtime, .NET Stuff, Codecs and others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things with wine a little easier, I recommend to check out "[Playonlinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/)". The thing is that playing games with wine often needs very specific settings for each game. And the playonlinux project provides a solution for that. They offer installer scripts that take care of some proven-to-work settings for each game, PoL has a GUI to keep the overview over different games and programs you installed and it provides a way to easily switch beetween different versions of wine without reinstalling (because sometimes you get regressions with newer wine versions for some games!).

Sorry I don't have the time to provide screenshots right now but have a look at their website. they have a PPA to integrate into your softwarecenter (though at the moment you have to take the PPA for 12.04 but this one works fine) or you download the ubuntu .deb file from their website.

Don't get fooled by the simplistic look - you can adjust anything manually after any installation via the GUI and if you want to get really into things their is a plugin system to add more Wine tools.

The program takes care of downloading and managing different wine versions. It also takes care of dependencies while it doesn't touch your systems wine verions installation.

hope that helps, 
piedro