# I can not install wine on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wine, dependencies

Can anyone help me to install Wine? I can not install it on Ubuntu 12.10. I always get the following message in the terminal:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 wine1.5 : Depends: wine1.5-i386 (= 1.5.22-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-droid
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: This problem has been already posted here: [Dependency error while installing WINE](http://askubuntu.com/q/204840/62483)

Answer (score 0):

Synaptic Package Manager > Edit > Fix Broken Packages

Then try again. Wine is really complex, running it up without Reading The Fine Manual was what I did at first and I regretted it almost instantly. You'll want to run seperate sandboxed instances of it and keep this page in bookmarks for installing specific programs : http://appdb.winehq.org/