# wine1.6 : Depends: libgettextpo0 but it is not installable

Tags: apt, wine

I get this problem every time I try and get wine 1.6 on Ubuntu 12.04. I have no idea how to fix it!  It just says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: libgettextpo0 but it is not installable
           Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1.7.1-actually1.6-0ubuntu1)
           Depends: binfmt-support (>= 1.1.2) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not installable
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not installable
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: By searching. http://askubuntu.com/questions/204840/dependency-error-while-installing-wine?rq=1 or http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to install wine from a PPA.

The wine version compatible with Ubuntu 12.04 is `1.4`. But it is going to install the version `1.6`. Here is the problem.

The packages those mentioned as `not installable` or `not going to be installed` are already installed from main repository.

They are not compatible with the `wine 1.6` which is to be installed.

The solution is either you have to remove the PPA and install wine from main repository (`wine 1.4`).

*Can be done with:*

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine
```

Or remove the packages those mentioned as `not installable` or `not going to be installed`. and then install wine from PPA.

```
sudo apt-get remove libgettextpo0 binfmt-support gnome-exe-thumbnailer kde-runtime fonts-droid ttf-mscorefonts-installer fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core winbind winetricks
```