# Wine won't install on fresh Ubuntu 13.10 64bit

Tags: installation, wine, dependencies

I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy on a Lenovo Thinkpad L512 laptop.

When I try to install Wine I get the following error:

```
root@gandalf:~# apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have followed the instructions at [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) and tried to add the i386 architecture as described at [Dependency error while installing WINE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204840/dependency-error-while-installing-wine), but neither of these have helped.

I also tried `apt-get install wine1.4`, but this depends on wine1.4-i386. I followed the chain of dependencies until I tried

```
apt-get install libudev1:i386
```

This wanted to remove 347 packages, including most of Ubuntu. Naturally I aborted this install.

I have also tried adding the Wine PPA and installing Wine 1.7, but this gives exactly the same errors.

Any suggestions? Please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to install newer version of wine from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa

Comment: Thanks @Rafal for this link. However, I still get the same error. 'apt-get install wine' results in 'wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed'.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully installed wine 1.7 on Ubuntu 13.10 64 Bit following [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20130906145422/http://www.itworld.com/software/371219/install-wine-171-ubuntu-1310-saucy-salamander)