# Cannot Install Programs Through Terminal on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: wine, software-installation

I recently made Ubuntu 12.0.4 bootable through my flashdrive. I've done this before, and have had no problems on previous flashdrives; the only problem I ran into then was I ran out of space, and now I reformatted my flashdrive to give me more space. The program I am trying to install is Wine 1.7, and the instructions given [here](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) aren't working for me this time. When I try and install it through terminal, I get this message every time:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.12-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.12-0ubuntu1)
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not installable
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not installable
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If anyone knows what this means I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Don't think that worked for me.

Comment: Are you trying to install wine on Ubuntu live disk?

Comment: I'll be honest I have no idea what that means. All I can say is I'm trying to install it on Ubuntu 12.04.3 which is running on my flashdrive.

Comment: And try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/215965/202806) answer.

Comment: why didn't you try to install Ubuntu on your HDD?

Comment: This is my work laptop, and I didn't want to possible put anything on the HDD (which is actually a SSD) that could mess it up. I don't know enough about computer software to mess with something like that.

Comment: Please note that if you install any programs on Ubuntu live disk,it will be erased when the system restarts.For this you have to make the live USB persistant.

Comment: I just tried that second method you posted, and that file is already there. I did the rest of the process and I get the same result.

Comment: Oh now I know what you mean about the live disk. I did make a persistant file of 4 gigs or so (since it's only an 8 gig flashdrive).

Comment: see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Answer (score 0):

try removing wine repo from sources.list, updates sources.list (sudo apt-get update) 
And if required add the latest repo info into the list and again update the list.

Try installing wine now.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get check does the trick. You might want to use also apt-get autoclean && apt-get autoremove