# Trying to install wine on 14.04, have tried removing all wine related but still no joy

Tags: wine, package-management, dependencies

After alot of dependency problems decided to remove all wine related packages
from synaptic.

Recently upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04.

Do not understand what is happening.
Get depends wine1.6-i386, when I try to install that get cmslib2-2 dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine winetricks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
2014-08-28_15:28 ~
$
```

Comment: See also some of the answers in [Dependency error while installing WINE](http://askubuntu.com/q/204840/22949) and [Why is Wine not installable on my system?](http://askubuntu.com/q/204393/22949) (though probably not the multi-arch related solutions, as that's unlikely to be a problem on 14.04).

Answer (score 0):

First try setting the architecture:

```
dpkg --add-architecture
```

Then purge and add the ppa again.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa && sudo apt-get update
```

And now try installing the dependency

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

For more information, please visit [Configuring Architecture](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO).

Hope it helps.